# How do you ignore a physics body with a RayCast in cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, raycasting

I am using the cocos2d-x framework to create a side scrolling runner.  The player sprite needs to hug the ground, but there are other physics objects that may go underneath the player.  How do I make the RayCast ignore those objects? I'm using the cocos2d-x RayCast.  Any help is appreciated.